# I want to remove rows where a specific value doesn't increase. Is there a faster/more elegant way?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with `30 columns`, `1.000.000 rows` and about `150 MB` size. One column is categorical with 7 different elements and another column (`Depth`) contains mostly increasing numbers. The graph for each of the elements looks more or less like this.

I tried to save the column `Depth` as series and iterate through it while dropping rows that won't match the criteria. This was reeeeeaaaally slow.
Afterwards I added a boolean column to the dataframe which indicates if it will be dropped or not, so I could drop the rows in the end in a single step. Still slow. My last try (the code to it is in this post) was to create a boolean list to save the fact if it passes the criteria there. Still really slow (about 5 hours).

```
    dropList = [True]*len(df.index)
    for element in elements:
        currentMax = 0
        minIdx = df.loc[df['Element']==element]['Depth'].index.min()
        maxIdx = df.loc[df['Element']==element]['Depth'].index.max()
        for x in range(minIdx,maxIdx):
            if df.loc[df['Element']==element]['Depth'][x] < currentMax:
                dropList[x]=False
            else:
                currentMax = df.loc[df['Element']==element]['Depth'][x]
```

df: The main dataframe

elements: a list with the 7 different elements (same as in the categorical column in df)

All rows in an element, where the value `Depth` isn't bigger than all previous ones should be dropped. With the next element it should start with 0 again.

Example:

```
Input:         'Depth' = [0 1 2 3 4 2 3 5 6]
      'AnyOtherColumn' = [a b c d e f g h i]

Output:            'Depth' [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
        'AnyOtherColumn' = [a b c d e h i]
```

This should apply to whole rows in the dataframe of course.

Is there a way to get this faster?

EDIT:
The whole rows of the input dataframe should stay as they are. Just the ones where the 'Depth' does not increase should be dropped.

EDIT2: 
The remaining rows should stay in their initial order.

Comment: can you add 1 more column and the expected output for both columns?

Answer (score 0):

How about you take a 2-step approach. First you use a fast sorting algorithm (for example Quicksort) and next you get rid of all the duplicates?

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunatelly the remaining rows should stay in the initial order. I forgot to mention this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a way thats faster. Here is the code:

```
    dropList = [True]*len(df.index)
    for element in elements:
        currentMax = 0
        minIdx = df.loc[df['Element']==element]['Tiefe'].index.min()
        # maxIdx = df.loc[df['Element']==element]['Tiefe'].index.max()
        elementList = df.loc[df['Element']==element]['Tiefe'].to_list()

        for x in tqdm(range(len(elementList))):
            if elementList[x] < currentMax:
                dropList[x+minIdx]=False
            else:
                currentMax = elementList[x]
```

I took the column and saved it as a list. To preserve, the index of the dataframe I saved the lowest one and within the loop it gets added again.

Overall it seems the problem was the `loc` function. From initially 5 hours runtime, its now about 10 seconds.